# Simpler way to delete JPA mapped tables records

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, rest, jpa

Is there any simpler way to delete the records of table with are mapped by @OneToMany and @ManyToOne JPA mapping. Currently I am using PostgreSQL as my database. There are 1000 records ranging from 0 to 999 which I want to delete, and rest I want to keep. As deleting every record with deletion of there references(foreign key) will be very hectic. Just want a simpler way to do this.

Comment: delete records from id =0 to id = 999

Comment: Well if they are dummy records and you are about to delete everything in your database, you could have recreated your database by changing your `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` in your Persistence.xml file to `drop-and-create`

Comment: No I have merged other data from other DB, So if I delete the database then everything will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always execute a `DELETE` query in JPA:

```java
int rowsDeleted = entityManager
    .createQuery("DELETE FROM MyEntity WHERE id >= 0 AND id <=999")
    .executeUpdate();
```

If there are foreign keys, you need some extra work:

```java
int childRowsDeleted = entityManager
    .createQuery("DELETE FROM MyChildEntity WHERE parent.id >= 0 AND parent.id <=999")
    .executeUpdate();
int rowsDeleted = entityManager
    .createQuery("DELETE FROM MyEntity WHERE id >= 0 AND id <=999")
    .executeUpdate();
```

If there are many foreign keys, perhaps you can consider JPA cascade remove:

```java
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
```

and then `entityManager.remove()` each entity but this will have performance implications since you will end up with *many* `DELETE` queries, each deleting a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Got this with introducing @DeleteMapping, and it worked without even using
" @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)" this annotation above the mapped variable declaration in the child class
[https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/#get-paginated-posts-get-postspage0size2sortcreatedatdesc], We can follow this link to get a complete overview.

```
 @DeleteMapping("/posts/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletePost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
        return postRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
            postRepository.delete(post);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
    }
```

Comment: Now I can keep the Repository part in the loop and that it.